# ! Undefined control sequence for definition inside a definition

Tags: errors

In the following code

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

%\def\pocz#1--#2.{#1 do #2} 
\def\zakres#1{\def\poko##1{#1.} #1 and \poko{} }

%\poko

\zakres{11--34}
\end{document}
```

I wanted to add `.` after the argument of `\zakres` and then to define makro `\pocz` with two arguments separated by `--` and `.`.

To my surprise, even `\zakres` without `{}` after `\poko` doesn't work. Moreover, uncommented `\poko` gives `! Undefined control sequence` error.

Whery is **my** error?

**Edit:** Putting `\poko` past `\zakres` gives even worse result.

Comment: You define `\poko` inside of `\zakres`, so `\poko` is not defined until `\zakres` was executed. Also `\poko` must be called with an argument.

Comment: @siracusa Putting `\poko` after `\zakres` gives the `waiting star' error. It is in some way unfinished, but I do not see, how.

Comment: Because the commented call is missing the parameter, so it takes  `\end` as parameter and then things go wrong

Comment: The code, as it stands now, doesn't raise errors.

Comment: @egreg Uncommenting `\poko` or putting it below `\zakres` shows the problem. Certainly, it is a version prepared for testing.

Comment: Don't use simply `\poko`. The command expects an argument, so you must use it as `\poko{something}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But why `\poko{}` gives `11-34.`? Theoretically, the argument of `\zakres` should be injected to `\poko`, but it isn't, although `\long` definition works.

Comment: You defined \poko as `#1.`,  and #1 is the argument of \zakres and so 11-34. Which output of `\poko{}` do you expect, when calling your \zakres command?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am expecting that `\poko` will work without closing `{}`. Moreover, after calling `\zakres` it should work separately. (The general goal is to split one argument into two, but the problem appears somewhere in the definition of `\zakres`).

Comment: Then define \poko as `\def\poko{#1.}` instead of giving it an argument (that you don't use anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

%\def\pocz#1--#2.{#1 do #2} 
\def\zakres#1{\def\poko##1{#1.} #1 and \poko{} }
```

at this point `\poko` is undefined.

```
%\poko

\zakres{11--34}
```

Now you have done `\def\poko#1{11--34.} 11--34 and \poko{}`

so `\poko` is defined to ignore its argument and typeseset 11-34. And you have typeset 11-34 and 11-34.

```
\poko{wibble}
```

Now `\poko` is called again so `wibble` is discarded and it typesets 11-34. again.

```
\end{document}
```

The third 11-34 would normally be in a new paragraph except that the example is using `standalone` which sets everything in a horizontal box.

Comment: Thank you! I was blind.